# Divide value in each cell by the geometric mean of a specific row across columns and log-transform it

Tags: r, dataframe, ln, geometric-mean

I would like to devide value in each cell by the geometric mean of a specific row across columns and log-transforme it (natural logarithm).

```
df1
      col1  col2  col3
row1  1     777   6
row2  136   1     665
row3  0     100   97
```

result

```
df_new
      col1    col2      col3
row1  -2.81   3.83     
row2           
row3
```

example of the calculation for the row1
[image]

Comment: Where does the 789 come from? I get the product of 1, 777 and 6 as 4662.

Comment: sorry it should be 4662, you are right. I will correct it

Comment: I get a different answer to Georgery but I think that solution is correct.

Comment: Where is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

geometric_mean <- function(x){
    exp(sum(log(x), na.rm = TRUE) / length(x))
}

yourCalculation <- function(x){
    log(x / geometric_mean(x))
}

myMatrix <- tribble(
    ~col1  ,~col2  ,~col3
    , 1     , 777   , 6
    , 136   , 1     , 665
    , 0     , 100   , 97) %>%
    as.matrix()


t(apply(myMatrix, 1, yourCalculation))

          col1      col2      col3
[1,] -2.815733  3.839707 -1.023974
[2,]  1.108508 -3.804147  2.695640
[3,]       NaN       Inf       Inf
```

**Important about geometric means**:
Don't calculate them like this: `prod(x)^(1/length(x))`. The problem with this is, that with already medium sized vectors `x` you are likely to run across your type boundaries when you multiply them all and so it won't compute. The `log()`-and-`exp()` way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below using `as.matrix` to convert data frame to matrix before math operation. Besides, you can use `Reduce(*,df1)` to achieve the product of columns in `df1`.

In this case, the one-liner solution is given as:

```
df_new <- data.frame(log(as.matrix(df1)/Reduce(`*`,df1)**(1/ncol(df1))))
```

such that

```
> df_new
          col1      col2      col3
row1 -2.815733  3.839707 -1.023974
row2  1.108508 -3.804147  2.695640
row3       NaN       Inf       Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your question. See [this discussion](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/nth-root-td885442.html) for alternative formulae for nth-root calculations.

```r
# set up the data
df <- data.frame(c(1, 777, 6), c(136, 1, 665), c(0, 100, 97))
df <- t(df)
colnames(df) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
rownames(df) <- NULL

# define a function to calculate the nth root
nthroot <- function(x, n){
    x^(1/n) 
}

# define a function to do your required transformations
cell_transformer <- function(x) {
    log(x/(nthroot(sapply(apply(df, 1, prod), sum), length(x))))
}

# apply the cell_transformer to your dataframe in a row-wise fashion
apply(df, 1, function(x) cell_transformer(x))    
#>         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> V1 -2.815733  2.096922      -Inf
#> V2  2.851293 -3.804147 0.8010229
#> V3       Inf       Inf       Inf
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>